# spawn UNKNOWN at ChildProcess.spawn

Tags: node.js, oauth, child-process, spawn, unknown-host

I got this error, now I don't know how to fix it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5tCDN.png)

I want to find a way to fix it